# Problem with bounds on surface integral.

Tags: differential-forms, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

Let $$S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:z=xy\},$$ and consider the $1$-form of $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $$\omega=(y^3+xz)dx-x^2dz.$$ I'm trying to compute the integral $\int_C \omega,$ where $C=S\cap \{x^2+y^2=1\}.$ Since $S=f^{-1}(\{0\})$, where $f(x,y,z)=xy-z$, it's a regular submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ so we can just consider the restriction of $\omega$ to $S$ (with pullback of the inmersion). I first computed the differential of the form, getting $$d\omega=3y^2dy\wedge dx+xdz\wedge dx-2x dx\wedge dz=-3y^2dx\wedge dy-3x dx\wedge dz,$$ and since $z=xy$, $dz=ydx+xdy$, so $$d\omega=-3y^2dx\wedge dy-3x^2dx\wedge dy=-3dx\wedge dy,$$ because $x^2+y^2=1$. Now by Stoke's theorem we have $$\int_C\omega=\int_M d\omega=-3\cdot \operatorname{Surface}(M),$$ where $M$ is some surface such as $C=\partial M$. Now i'm having troubles to visualize which manifold is exactly $M$ and how to compute its surface to apply Stoke's Theorem.

Comment: $M$ should be equal to $S \cap \{x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$ I believe? Not sure how to prove it, just going off of the $3\mathrm{D}$ plot of your situation. If true, then you can have a parameterisation of $M$: if you have $(x,y) = \cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)$, then $z = xy = \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{2}$, hence: $$M = \left\{\left(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta), \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{2}\right) \mid \theta \in [0, 2\pi)\right\}$$ in case that helps (probably not but who knows).

Comment: I think there's a typo in $d\omega=3y^2dy\wedge dx+xdz\wedge dz-2x dx\wedge dz=-3y^2dx\wedge dy-3x dx\wedge dz,$ in particular $xdz\wedge dz$ clearly isn't what was intended?

Comment: True, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A correct candidate of $M$ would be the surface parametrised by:
$$
(r,\phi)\in [0,1)\times[0,2\pi)\to\begin{pmatrix}
r\cos\phi \\
r\sin\phi \\
r^2\cos\phi\sin\phi
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(Bruno B only gave a parametrisation of $C$). You cannot use $x^2+y^2=1$ in calculating $d\omega$ since you'll be integrating in $M$ where $x^2+y^2<1$. If your calculation of $d\omega$ were correct, then yes the RHS would have been the area of its projection in the $xy$ plane, i.e. a unit disk. Starting from your penultimate expression for $d\omega$:
$$
d\omega=-3(x^2+y^2)dx\wedge dy
$$
I get:
$$
\int_M d\omega = \int_{x^2+y^2<1} -3(x^2+y^2)dxdy
$$
To actually compute it, the easiest way is to go to polar coordinates where I use:
$$
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2 &=r^2 & dx\wedge dy&= rdr\wedge d\phi
\end{align}
$$
(last equation being the Jacobian of polar coordinates), I get:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_M d\omega &= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 -3r^3drd\phi \\
&= -\frac{3\pi}{2}
\end{align}
$$

You can check the consistency with Stokes' formula. Using Bruno B's parametrisation of $C$:
$$
\gamma:\phi\in[0,2\pi)\to\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\phi \\
\sin\phi \\
\cos\phi\sin\phi
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the expression of $\omega$ on $C$:
$$
\omega = y^3dx-x^3dy
$$
you need to calculate:
$$
\int_C \omega = -\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin^4\phi+\cos^4\phi)d\phi
$$
which is straightforward using:
$$
\begin{align}
\cos^4\phi &= \frac{\cos(4\phi)+4\cos(2\phi)+3}{8} \\
\sin^4\phi &= \frac{\cos(4\phi)-4\cos(2\phi)+3}{8}
\end{align}
$$
so:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_C \omega &= -\left[\frac{\sin(4\phi)+4\sin(2\phi)+3\phi}{8}+\frac{\sin(4\phi)-4\sin(2\phi)+3\phi}{8}\right]_0^{2\pi} \\
&= -\frac{3\pi}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: +1. Compared to my pedestrian way of arriving at $-3r^3\,dr\wedge d\phi$ is there a short cut ?

Comment: I’ve added some intermediate steps. I think it’s slightly faster to calculate $d\omega$ in $x,y$ and then express in $r,\phi$ rather than first express $\omega$ in  $r,\phi$ then take the exterior derivative, since the OP already did the calculations in $x,y$.

Comment: Also I used the jacobian in polar coordinates. If I were to rederive it, it would add extra steps along the lines of what you wrote yourself.

Comment: Perfect. I also hope that the edit of my answer makes clear where @GuillermoGarcíaSáez' mistake actually was.

Answer (score 3):

Just a small remark if permitted, since I was puzzled by LPZ's elegant way of solving this.

The correct calculation of $d\omega$ is
$$\tag{1}
d\omega=3y^2\,dy\wedge dx+x\,dz\wedge dx-2x\,dx\wedge dz=-3y^2\,dx\wedge dy+3x\,dz\wedge dx\,.
$$
Using $z=xy$ it is correct to write  $dz=x\,dy+y\,dx$ and therefore
$$\tag{2}
d\omega=-3y^2\,dx\wedge dy-3x^2\,dx\wedge dy=-3(x^2+y^2)\,dx\wedge dy\,.
$$
It is however $\color{red}{incorrect}$ to use here the constraint for the *curve* $x^2+y^2=1$ to write the  form on the *surface* as $\color{red}{d\omega=-3\,dx\wedge dy}\,.$

To integrate $d\omega$ over $M$ with LPZ's parametrization we use
\begin{align}
dx&=\cos\phi\,dr-r\sin\phi\,d\phi\,,\\
dy&=\sin\phi\,dr+r\cos\phi\,d\phi\,,\\
dz&=2r\cos\phi\sin\phi\,dr-r^2\sin^2\phi\,d\phi+r^2\cos\phi\,d\phi
\end{align}
which gives
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
d\omega&=3r^3\sin^4\phi\,d\phi\wedge dr-\cancel{3r^3\sin^2\phi\cos^2\phi\,dr\wedge d\phi}\\
&~~~-6r^3\cos^2\phi\sin^2\phi\,dr\wedge d\phi-\cancel{3r^3\cos^2\phi\sin^2\phi\,d\phi\wedge dr}\\[2mm]
&~~~+3r^3\cos^4\phi\,d\phi\wedge dr\\[2mm]
&=-3r^3(\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi)^2\,dr\wedge d\phi\\[2mm]
&=-3r^3\,dr\wedge d\phi\,
\end{align}
when we use (1). When we use (2) we see this much more quickly from
$$
dx\wedge dy=r(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi)\,dr\wedge d\phi=r\,dr\wedge d\phi\,.
$$

Comment: @GuillermoGarcíaSáez I found a better explanation. See edit.

Comment: Thank you very much! +1